# Why did changing my xpath make my selenium click work consistently?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, navigation, wait

I am running a series of selenium tests with python. I have a navigation on the page I'm testing that has this structure:

```
<ul> 
 <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="#">
        <span> First nav </span>
    </a>
        <ul style="display:block">
         <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span> First subnav </span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Now I am clicking on the first subnav, that is the first span, but clicking on First nav to open up that list then first subnav. I implement a webdriverwait, to wait for the element to be visible and click on it via it's xpath,

```
//span[1]
```

I often got timeout exceptions waiting for the subnav span to be visible after clicking on the nav, which made me think something was wrong with clicking on the first nav to open up the list. So I changed the xpath of the first nav (//span[1]) to

```
//li[@class='has-sub']/descendant::span[text()='First subnav']
```

and I never get timeout exceptions when waiting for subnav span to be visible now. So seems like it's always clicking on the nav span every time to open it up and give me no timeout when trying to get to the subnav. Anyone have any idea why that is?

Here is my python code as well:

inside LoadCommPage class:

```
def click_element(self, by, locator):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, locator)))
        print "pressing element " + str(locator)
        self.driver.find_element(by, locator).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print "no clickable element in 10 sec"
        print self.traceback.format_exc()
        self.driver.close()
```

inside main test (load_comm_page is an instance of LoadCommPage, where click_clement is defined):

```
load_comm_page.click_element(*LoadCommPageLocators.sys_ops_tab)
```

And another class for the locators:

```
class LoadCommPageLocators(object):
firstnav_tab = (By.XPATH, "//li[@class='has-sub']/descendant::span[text()='First nav']")
```

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 1):

Xpath indexes begin at one, not 0 so the Xpath

```
//span[1]
```

is looking for the first span element in the html. Whereas

```
//span[2]
```

will look for the second span.

Comment: Wow really, good to know. That doesn't explain the behavior I saw though - sometimes it would click on the correct element and other times it wouldn't click on anything (timeout). No times would it click on the next span on the DOM.